# Conditionally add boolean attribute to a tag with xslt

Tags: xslt

Where unconditionally I would write, say,

```
    <season boolean:warm="true">
```

I would set an attribute conditionally via xslt but I don't know what syntax to use

```
    <season>
      <xsl:if ...>
        <xsl:attribute name="warm">
         true
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>
    </season>
```

the program which uses the result of this xslt fails to handle this variant

Comment: Is the problem with namespaces, perhaps? Your conditionally attribute is not being created with a namespace. Perhaps you can show the namespace for the "Boolean" prefix? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use namespaces in XSLT you have to declare them. Lets assume your source is something like:

```
<months>
    <month>January</month>
    <month>August</month>
</months>
```

Since you require a prefix in your attribute, you have to declare the namespace. You didn't show the namespace, so I will use a random string. The XSL below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
    xmlns:boolean="put-your-namespace-here">

    <xsl:template match="months">
        <seasons><xsl:apply-templates/></seasons>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="month">
        <season>
            <xsl:if test="text() = 'August'">
                <xsl:attribute name="boolean:warm">true</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </season>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Will produce the following result:

```
<seasons xmlns:boolean="put-your-namespace-here">
    <season>January</season>
    <season boolean:warm="true">August</season>
</seasons>
```